# perl multiline string regex

Tags: regex, perl

I try to find all the strings (between " or ') in a file by reading the file line by line.

```
my @strings = ();
open FILE, $file or die "File operation failed: $!";
foreach my $line (<FILE>) {
    push(@strings, $1) if /(['"].*['"])/g;
}
close FILE;
```

The problem is this code work only for strings on a single line.

```
print "single line string";
```

But I have to match also multiline strings like :

```
print "This is a
multiligne
string";
```

How can I do ?

By the way, I know my regex isn't good enough. Because it should match strings that start with " and finish with " (same with single quotes) but not if we have `"not correct string'`

**Update** : my new code is

```
my @strings = ();
open FILE, $file or die "File operation failed: $!";
local $/;
foreach my $line (<FILE>) {
    push(@strings, grep { defined and /["']/ } quotewords('\s+', 1, $_));
}
close FILE;
```

but if the data is :

```
print $time . "single line \n";
print "This is a
multiline
string";
print 'single quote string';
print "string with variable ".$time." after variable";
```

I should get :

```
"single line \n"
"This is a
multiline
string"
'single quote string'
"string with variable "
" after variable"
```

Comment: Using `.*` there is wrong, since it is greedy. If you make this a multiline match, you will match only one time, most of the file. I.e. `print "foo"; print "bar\nbar";` will return `"foo"; print "bar\nbar"`

Comment: what do you advise me then please?

Comment: Posted an answer with my recommendation.

Comment: Normally, the `s` flag for perl regular expressions allows `\s` to match newlines, but your real problem here is `foreach my $line (<FILE>)`.  You'll never have a multiline value for `$line` because you're explicitly reading it one line at a time.  You'll probably need to slurp the whole file before you start matching.

Comment: yes you're right I've changed following TLP's recommendation but it still doesn't work completely as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are two regex's for parsing either single or double quotes.  Note, that I've slurped all the data in order to be able to catch multiline strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $squo_re = qr{'(?:(?>[^'\\]*)|\\.)*'};
my $dquo_re = qr{"(?:(?>[^"\\]*)|\\.)*"};

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

while ($data =~ /($squo_re|$dquo_re)/g) {
    print "<$1>\n";
}

__DATA__
print $time . "single line \n";
print "This is a
multiline
string";
print 'single quote string';
print "string with variable ".$time." after variable";
```

However, because you're trying to parse perl code, the cleanest way of doing it will be to use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

# Find all the barewords within the doc
my $strings = $doc->find( 'PPI::Token::Quote' );
for (@$strings) {
    print '<', $_->content, ">\n";
}

__DATA__
print $time . "single line \n";
print "This is a
multiline
string";
print 'single quote string';
print "string with variable ".$time." after variable";
```

Both methods output:

```
<"single line \n">
<"This is a
multiline
string">
<'single quote string'>
<"string with variable ">
<" after variable">
```

**Update about (?> ... )**

The following is an annotated version of the double quote regular expression.

```
my $dquo_re = qr{
    "
        (?:                # Non-capturing group - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings
            (?>            # Independent Subexpression to prevent backtracking (this is for efficiency only) - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-independent-subexpressions-to-prevent-backtracking
                [^"\\]*    # All characters NOT a " or \
            )
        |
            \\.            # Backslash followed by any escaped character
        )*                 # Any number of the preceeding or'd group
    "
    }x;
```

The [independent subexpression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-independent-subexpressions-to-prevent-backtracking) `(?> ... )` it not actually required for this regex to work.  It is intended to prevent backtracking because there is only one way for a quoted string to match, either we find a ending quote using the above rules or we don't.

The subexpression is a lot more useful when dealing with a recursive regex, but I've always used it in this case.  I'll have to benchmark at a later to to decide if it's actually just a premature optimization.

**Update about Comments**

To avoid comments, you can just use the `PPI` solution that I already proposed.  It's meant to parse perl code and will already work as it is.

However, given this is a lab assignment, a regex solution would be to setup a second capturing group in your loop for finding comments:

```
while ($data =~ /($squo_re|$dquo_re)|($comment_re)/g) {
    my $quote = $1,
    my $comment = $2;

    if (defined $quote) {
        print "<$quote>\n";
    } elsif ($defined $comment) {
        print "Comment - $comment\n";
    }
}
```

The above will match either a quoted string or a comment.  Which capture actually matched will be defined so you can know which was found.  You will have to come up with the regular expression for finding a comment on your own though.

Comment: Thanks the first method works perfectly with my tests.

Comment: Could you add an explanation for your regex? What is the purpose of the `(?>` parentheses?

Comment: One more thing if I may, how to ignore the string if it is in a comment ? Thanks again. (it may be too off topic, don't answer in this case)

Comment: I've created updates about independent subexpressions and how to exclude comments.