# Perl Regex - print all matches found in a string

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, printing

Hopefully there isn't a major issue with this repost, I just needed some extra info that somehow slipped my mine the first time.

In the program I'm working on, I'm attempting to take in a txt file, then print the bits of txt contained in a pair of quotation marks.

Below is what I had. (Assume I've taken in the txt file and put it into an array with each line as an array element.) It works, but if a line has 2+ strings obviously it only prints the first.

What would be a clean way of printing all matches?

I tried iterating through `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc, and print them `if ne "";`. But this didn't seem to work.

```
txt file contents:


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur "adipisicing elit"
sed "do" eiusmod tempor "incididunt"
ut "labore et dolore" magna aliqua


CODE:
foreach(@arr)
{
    print "$1\n" if /(".*?")/g;
}
```

Comment: Do you have escaped quotes? `"this is an \"escaped\" quote"`. Or line breaks inside the quoted strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23086883/725418

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while ($subject =~ m/"(.*?)"/sig) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Might take a while for me to understand how though haha!

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop

```
foreach (@arr) {
    while (/(".*?")/g) {
        print "$1";
    }
}
```