# Parsing multiline quoted strings in a large file

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I'm working on a web publishing localization project, where I am beginning with an established website written in English that is published by a CMS. The file contains headers that identify pages, subheads that identify the sections of each page, and pairs of strings that illustrate the original phrase on the English website and the translated phrase in a different language.

Each translation file contains only one language. So for the Spanish translation, an excerpt of representative file looks like this:

```
## 3602 Example Page

    ### Title

        'Example Page' => 'Página de ejemplo',

    ### Body

        'This is an example of a string that came from an example page.' => 'Este es un ejemplo de una cadena que proviene de una página de ejemplo.',
        'Parsing this would be relatively simple, except that
occasionally, 
there are carriage returns thrown into the text without warning.' => 'Parsear esto sería relativamente simple, excepto que
ocasionalmente, 
hay retornos de carro lanzados en el texto sin previo aviso.',

    ### Extended


## 3704 About Us

    ### Title

        'About Us' => 'Sobre nosotros',

    ### Body

        'This text takes the place of text which would identify the client.' => 'Este texto toma el lugar del texto que identificaría al cliente.',
        q{I passed the English text though Google Translate. Don't think for a moment that these passages are professionally translated!} => q{Pasé el texto en inglés a través de Google Translate. ¡No piense por un momento que estos pasajes son traducidos profesionalmente!},

    ### Extended
```

What I'm trying to do is write a Perl script that parses this file, locates the page in the CMS, then replaces the original English string with the translated string, and saves the page in the CMS for subsequent publishing.

The CMS I'm using has a Perl API, so the entire script is written in Perl.

My approach up to now has been to read the file a line at a time, and use regular expressions to identify the important contents of the file using regular expressions.

The critical part of this code is shown below:

```perl
    while (defined($current_line = <FILE>))
    {
        chomp $current_line;
        $total_lines++;

        ##########
        #
        # We need to parse the file, line-by-line, to determine what each line represents.
        #
        # If the $current_phrase is populated at the beginning of the case statement,
        # we know that the 
        #
        # When we start parsing, $current_page_id is zero (0). If we hit a page selector and
        # the page ID is something other than zero, we need to save the previous page.
        #
        ##########  

        if (length($current_phrase) > 0) {
            if ($current_line =~ /(.*\')\s=>\'(.*)/) {
                $current_phrase .= '\n' . $1;
            }
        }

        elsif ($current_line =~ qr/##\s(\d+)\s.+/mp) {

            ##########
            #
            # $1 is the page ID number.
            #
            ##########

            if ($current_page_id != int($1)) {
                print "\nPage $1 selector\n";
                $current_page_id = int($1);
                $current_page_change_count = 0;
                $current_page_section_name = '';
                $current_page_section_content = '';
                $current_phrase = '';

            }



        } elsif ($current_line =~ qr/###\s(.+)/mp) {

            ##########
            #
            # $1 is the name of the page section.
            #
            # We have to figure out if the page section is the same as the one that we
            # have been processing.
            #
            ##########

            print "\nPage Section Delimiter: " . $1 . "\n";

            if ($1 ne $current_page_section_name) {

                ##########
                #
                # Since $1 is not $current_page_section_name, we need to put
                # $current_page_section_content into the page section where it belongs.
                # 
                # $current_page_section_name refers to the section of the page with changes.
                #
                ##########

                $current_page_section_name = $1;

            }

        } elsif (($current_line =~ qr/'((?:(?>[^'\\]*)|\\.)*)' => '((?:(?>[^'\\]*)|\\.)*)',/mp) || ($current_line =~ qr/q\{((?:(?>[^}\\]*)|\\.*))} => q\{((?:(?>[^}\\]*)|\\.*))},/mp)){

                ##########
                #
                # The complex regular expression above is intended to capture multi-line
                # variants of either the 'phrase' or q{phrase} pattern.
                # 
                # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086883/perl-multiline-string-regex
                # for some idea how the single quote pattern was found. We had to work up the
                # q{phrase} pattern ourselves.
                #
                #
                ##########          

            $current_page_change_count++;
            $total_change_count++;
            print "Phrase " . $current_page_change_count . ", original: " . $1 . ", change to: " . $2 . "\n\n";

        } elsif (($current_line =~ qr/^\s+?\'(.+)[^\'],?\s?/mp) || ($current_line =~ qr/^\s+?q\{(.+)[^}],?\s?/mp)) {

                ##########
                #
                # The biggest unresolved issue with the while loop is how
                # to identify the unterminated strings that begin with
                # a single quote or the q{ construct.
                #
                # The regular expression above is an attempt to match both cases.
                #
                # Eventually, I will have to search for the end of the
                # string, the => construct, and the translated phrase.
                #
                ##########  

            print "Unterminated string: " . $current_line . "\n";
        } elsif (($current_line =~ qr/^\s+/mp) || (length($current_line) == 0)) {
            print "Blank line.\n";
            $total_blank_lines++;
        } else {
            #
            # Want to ignore, not print this.
            print "Something else:  \'" . $current_line . "\'\n";
            #
            $total_blank_lines++;
        }


    }

    print "\nTotal lines: " . $total_lines . "\n";
    print "\nTotal blank lines: " . $total_blank_lines . "\n";
    print "Total change count: " . $total_change_count . "\n";
```

As I say in the code comments, the biggest issue I'm running into is crafting a regular expression that identifies unterminated strings, which are what I call phrases from the English version of the website that begin with a single quote or the `q{` construct and, at some point in the line of text, have a carriage return terminator.

The current regular expression is not selective enough on its own, but that may be OK because the previous regular expressions select other parts of the file correctly.

Where I'm looking for help is:

1. Ensuring that this regular expression is sufficiently selective.
2. Figuring out how to accumulate all of the text that should be part of the `$current_phrase`, so the phrase spans multiple lines.
3. Figuring out a way forward, so I can develop other regular expressions to identify the other multi-line translation pair fragments that would be necessary to handle a file of this nature.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Look into [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) to do a lot of the heavy lifting of extracting the quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your input has Perl-style #comments, Perl-style fat commas to associate English and foreign text, and even the Perl `q{}` construction. It seems like you really want to use Perl to analyze this file. If that's the case (and if you can always trust your input hasn't been maliciously tampered with), you can try something like:

```
@sections = split /^(\s*#[^\n]*)/m, $INPUT; # $INPUT is the whole file
foreach $section (@sections) {
    next unless $section =~ /\S/;
    if ($section =~ /^\s*##\s(\d+)\s.+/) {
        $page_number = $1;
    } elsif ($section =~ /^\s*###\s(.+)/) {
        $page_section = $1;
    } elsif ($section =~ /=>/) {
        %phrases = eval( "($section)" );
        # manipulate keys and values of phrases
    }
}
```

If this is not the direction you wanted to go in, I think you'd be happier rewriting the input in a standard format with mature, battle-tested parsers, like JSON.

```
{"source":"en-US", "dest":"es-ES",
[{"pageTitle":"Example Page", "pageNumber":3602,
 "sections":[{"sectionName":"Title", "phrases":{
 "Example Page":"Página de ejemplo"}},
 {"sectionName":"Body","phrases":{
 "This is an example of a string that came from an example page.":
 "Este es un ejemplo de una cadena que proviene de una página de ejemplo.",
 ... }}]]}
```

Comment: We generate the translation base file with another Perl script. The format of the files was specified in advance, partly because we were able to leverage some code from a related project that has existed for many years.

Comment: @DaveAiello I second the suggestion to change to a well supported format (JSON or YAML for example), if at all possible.  Otherwise, note that for that nice `eval` to work the translations need be valid Perl (in your given sample all are). Then, if you need to clean out those newlines and any extra spaces, you'll need to do that as well (replace each stretch of consecutive "whitespace" with a single space).

Comment: @zdim Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, I can't work with formats that are as machine readable as JSON and YAML in this application. I needed to generate the translatable phrases in a format that was extremely human-readable.

The issues with the way the translatable phrases came out of the CMS initially were 1) someone who originally entered the page text inserted carriage returns into the text, thinking these carriage returns changed the appearance of the text when it was rendered by the CMS, and 2) the CMS page editor accepted these carriage returns.

Comment: @DaveAiello Sure, you know your project; I only meant to say that custom formats can keep bringing little issues.  But then the code here answers your query, no?  The linebreaks are really easy to clean out once you have those text segments extracted (like `s/\s+/ /g` for example).

Comment: @DaveAiello  [ Btw, have you ever dealt with [YAML](https://yaml.org/)? It is _very_ nice to look at.  For example, the web page at the link is a valid YAML document (well, save for a few glitches). ]